# Would lotion pumps work in a vacuum?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, vacuum, air

I'm just trying to understand how a lotion pump works. I watched this video and it's explained that it's due to the difference in air pressure.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJVL5zXIPLA&ab_channel=JenWang

Does this mean that if we put a lotion pump in a vacuum, when we press on the head, the liquid won't be able to come up because there's no air? For some reason, instinctively I thought it had to do with the pump literally squeezing the liquid out due to the decrease in volume since there's nowhere for the liquid to move to.

Answer (score 3):

The pump has a reservoir (the bottle part) and a chamber (the short fat cylinder on the straw and spring assembly).

If the chamber is filled with liquid, depressing the actuator closes a valve at the bottom and opens a valve at the top and squeezes the liquid out through the top by reducing the amount of space available for the liquid inside the chamber.

When the actuator spring pushes the actuator back up into its resting position, the valve at the bottom opens and the valve at the top closes. Gas pressure inside the reservoir pushes liquid from the reservoir up into the chamber.

If you took away the gas pressure (and somehow kept the liquid from boiling fast enough to replenish it), the pump would dispense the one squirt of liquid that was stored inside the chamber, but the chamber would not refill, so that would be the last squirt.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a brand new lotion pump bottle from Earth and bring it to a vacuum, your first issue would be that the bottle might explode, since there's no outside pressure pushing in. So let's assume the bottle is strong enough for this not to happen.

You must also ensure that your vacuum is at a normal temperature. Most any vacuum in a lab on Earth can have this property (since it may be at thermal equilibrium with its surroundings), but out in deep space it's 3 Kelvin. If it's too cold there's a high chance then that any liquid inside the bottle will freeze solid. The pump components (plastic, rubber, and metal) may also become extremely hard and brittle, and may not work/move anymore.

Assuming the vacuum is kept at a reasonable temperature... Usually with new lotion bottles you need to twist the top a bit to "unlock" the pump. As soon as you unlock it, all air inside the piston will rush out, and depending on the liquid/lotion that may start coming out as well, until the pump comes all the way up and seals the chamber. This is what you were mentioning, I believe. It would basically be like somebody is sucking infinitely hard (i.e. creating perfect vacuum in their mouth) through a straw.

Comment: vacuums created on earth are perfectly usual and are not 3K.  Nor are all things in space 3 K. The JWST takes complicated measures to *cool* itself to 50 K. and temperature is also irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @tobalt You're right, I guess I had space in mind but any simple vacuum on Earth would equilibrate to the surrounding temperature. I edited my response to reflect this. The surface of the star may not be 3K, but neither is the pressure that of a vacuum there either (it's about half a torr). Temperature isn't totally irrelevant to the question because if the OP somehow went to space to conduct this experiment, and wasn't careful with the temperature, they might find very different results than what they'd find on Earth.

Comment: I think you're confused about what vacuum temperature means. A vacuum by definition doesn't have an average molecular kinetic energy. (The space contains a very dilute gas which has an average molecular kinetic energy but that gas barely participates in energy exchange.) Rather the temperature of the vacuum is related to the radiation flux through the space.

Comment: The 3K figure you listed is the radiation temperature of the CMB - leftover radiation from the very bright very early universe. The radiation temperature of the Sun at a distance equal to mean Earth orbit is entirely different (around 400K, the same as the temperature you feel if you open an oven on low heat, leave it open for a few seconds to let the hot air come out, and stick your hand inside). **Space** isn't cold. **Dark space** is cold.

Comment: @gs "Vacuum" only means lower pressure than the surrounding, with a "better" vacuum achieving a lower pressure. It makes no mention to the temperature, you can have a vacuum at any temperature (assuming you have enough particles for the macroscopic concept of pressure and temperature to exist). Of course average kinetic energy of massive particles isn't the only contributor to thermal energy, so is radiation. What you mentioned about the temperature out in space at the Earth's radius... good point, I hadn't thought of that. Satellites get really hot when they face the sun, you're right.

Comment: The temperature *of the diffuse gas* of Earth's extreme upper atmosphere, where those satellites are, is around 2500K, a thousand degrees hotter than the melting point of the steel those satellites are made of. The gas has almost nothing to do with the detectable temperature, which is about 400K in sunlight, the same as if the gas wasn't there at all.